# Code Coverage Report Seems Broken Like Without CSS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-databricks, cicd, databricks-connect, pytest-cov

I have a pipeline to connect with databricks & run the databricks notebooks under databricks github repo for unit testing using pytest library. So, Pytest command should execute the notebooks to generate the test results & code coverage.

My pipeline was running on a self-hosted agent pool where docker containers are working on the execution. I have installed pre necessary software's & libraries with the docker image and deployed on top of containers.

Below are the exact lines written on YML file,

```
- script: |
    pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines pytest-cov opencensus opencensus-ext-azure
    pip install -U databricks-connect==9.1.*
    pip install databricks-cli
   apt-get update && apt-get install -y junit cobertura
   
    export DATABRICKS_HOST=$(Databricks_URL)
    export DATABRICKS_TOKEN=$(Databricks_Temp_Token)
    export DATABRICKS_CLUSTER_ID=$(DATABRICKS_CLUSTER_ID)
    export DATABRICKS_ORG_ID=$(DATABRICKS_ORG_ID)
  displayName: 'Load Python dependencies'
 
- checkout: self
persistCredentials: true
clean: true 
 
- script: |
    
    python -m pytest --junit-xml=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/logs/TEST-LOCAL.xml --report-dir=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/logs/ --cov=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/tests/ --cov-report=html:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/logs/ $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/tests/test_*.py --no-coverage-upload

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
    summaryFileLocation: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/coverage.xml'
    reportDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/logs/'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-LOCAL.xml'    
    publishRunAttachments: true
    failTaskOnFailedTests: true
```

If I run the Pytest command without --no-coverage-upload option, MS agent doesn't throw any error. It was generated code coverage with proper styling. But with self hosted agent, it throws below error,

```
##[error]Unable to process command '##vso[codecoverage.publish codecoveragetool=Cobertura;summaryfile=/agent_works/ado_agent_wrk-nYQREz/ado_agent_wrk-nYQuVz/1/s/coverage.xml;reportdirectory=/agent_works/ado_agent_wrk-nYQREz/ado_agent_wrk-nYQREz/1/s/logs;]' successfully. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)

##[error]File '/agent_works/ado_agent_wrk-nYQREz/ado_agent_wrk-nYQREz/1/s/coverage.xml' does not exist or is not accessible.
```

So, I have added --no-coverage-upload option to resolve the above issue. But once pytest generated the code coverage report successfully (with index.html, style.css, everything), it is not getting loaded with proper styling even though i pointed correct report directory location while publish code coverage. It looks like below,

I am bit confused what needs to be done from self hosted agent side since it's working fine on MS agents? I hope avoiding --no-coverage-upload will fix this issue. But avoid that will make an issue as i mentioned.

**Is Azure blocking the CSS generated by pytest on source repository ? Is --no-coverage-upload required for self-hosted agent to generate code coverage report ? Why CSS is not getting reflected in coverage report even i can able to view the css through yml scripts ? How to overcome this css broken issue ?**

I have tried this with self hosted agent and it keeps showing broken report. I am expecting a fix cause it bothers me.

Comment: As you mentioned it works in the MS hosted agent and doesn't work in the self-hosted agent, you can download the detailed logs and compare the difference between self-hosted agent and Microsoft hosted agent. To see more detailed logs, you can add a variable named `system.debug` and set its value to `true`.   By the way, you said "It looks like below" but seems the screenshot is missing in the question.